# Apache solr appending the data in a field

Tags: php, curl, solr

I am indexing my data in Apache solr using this command from curl

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true" -F "myfile=@/home/ww.pdf"
```

Can i add more contents to attr_contents attribute after this running this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-place updates (changing only one field of an existing record) are not possible in present versions of Solr. You will need to re-index the whole document.

But if you want to set a field when you index a rich document (like a PDF), use `literal.my_field=some_val`. You are setting the `id` this way in the command you included.